# boost::fiber scheduling - when and how

Tags: c++, boost, fibers

According to the documentation

> the currently-running fiber retains control until it invokes some
>   operation that passes control to the manager

I can think about only one operation - `boost::this_fiber::yield` which may cause control switch from fiber to fiber. However, when I run something like

```
bf::fiber([](){std::cout << "Bang!" << std::endl;}).detach();
bf::fiber([](){std::cout << "Bung!" << std::endl;}).detach();
```

I get output like

> Bang!Bung!
>   
> \n
>   
> \n

Which means control was passed between `<<` operators from one fiber to another. How it could happen? Why? What is the general definition of controll passing from fiber to fiber in the context of `boost::fiber` library?

EDIT001:
Cant get away without code:

```
#include <boost/fiber/fiber.hpp>
#include <boost/fiber/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/fiber/barrier.hpp>
#include <boost/fiber/algo/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fiber/algo/work_stealing.hpp>

namespace bf = boost::fibers;

class GreenExecutor
{
    std::thread worker;
    bf::condition_variable_any cv;
    bf::mutex mtx;
    bf::barrier barrier;
public:
    GreenExecutor() : barrier {2}
    {   
        worker = std::thread([this] {
            bf::use_scheduling_algorithm<bf::algo::work_stealing>(2);
            // wait till all threads joining the work stealing have been registered
            barrier.wait();
            mtx.lock();
            // suspend main-fiber from the worker thread
            cv.wait(mtx);
            mtx.unlock();
        });
        bf::use_scheduling_algorithm<bf::algo::work_stealing>(2);
        // wait till all threads have been registered the scheduling algorithm
        barrier.wait();
    }

    template<typename T>
    void PostWork(T&& functor)
    {
        bf::fiber {std::move(functor)}.detach();
    }

    ~GreenExecutor()
    {
        cv.notify_all();
        worker.join();
    }
};

int main()
{
    GreenExecutor executor;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    int i = 0;
    for (auto j = 0ul; j < 10; ++j) {
        executor.PostWork([idx {++i}]() {
            auto res = pow(sqrt(sin(cos(tan(idx)))), M_1_PI);
            std::cout << idx << " - " << res << std::endl;
        });
    }
    while (true) {
        boost::this_fiber::yield();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

> 2 - 1 - -nan
>   0.503334 3 - 4 - 0.861055
>   0.971884 5 - 6 - 0.968536
>   -nan 7 - 8 - 0.921959
>   0.9580699
>    - 10 - 0.948075
>   0.961811

Comment: Please include a minimal, self-contained example that shows the problem.

Comment: Oh, I guess I figured it out... No magic, fibers are executed in two threads in this case, not in one as I initially thought, the main one and the one created in constructor, thus mixing the output to `std::cout`

Comment: Feel free to self-answer. I think this could surprise others and as such is helpful

Comment: BTW, my assumption about `yield` is correct, right? this is the only way to switch control from one fiber to another?

Comment: It's not a "switch" as such. It's an opportunity got the scheduler to _maybe_ switch.  And yes, non-preemptive (aka cooperative) multi-tasking implies you need to yield control explicitly. Of course, you can still combine with preemptive multitasking as you have found out in your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there were a couple of things I missed, first, my conclusion was based on misunderstanding of how stuff works in `boost::fiber`
The line in the constructor mentioned in the question
`bf::use_scheduling_algorithm<bf::algo::work_stealing>(2);`
was installing the scheduler in the thread where the `GreenExecutor` instance was created (in the main thread) so, when launching two worker `fiber`s I was actually initiating two threads which are going to process submitted `fiber`s which in turn would process these `fibers` asynchronously thus mixing the `std::cout` output. No magic, everything works as expected, the `boost::fiber::yield` still is the only option to pass control from one fiber to another

Comment: I find that your code stalls before doing any work (using MSVC++ 19.25, boost 1.73). But move the `use_scheduling_algorithm` call on the main thread down to after the other thread is created, and it works. Don't ask me why, it's just a gamble that paid off.

Comment: Back then I ran it (AFAIR) on Linux with GCC. Maybe things changed. But you did the right thing. Take a look here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/fiber/worker.html

Comment: Updated the example to avoid confusion in the future